# getting an error while updating confluence page table using rest api

Tags: python, json

Currently I'm getting this error when I tried to update the confluence page.
error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

this is my code:

```
import re
import bs4
import requests

headers={'Authorization': 'Basic token'}
dataurl='https://page/wiki/rest/api/content/1212121212?expand=body.storage'
contentx = requests.get(address, headers=headers).json()
content=contentx['body']['storage']['value']
regex = re.compile(r"<td>i need to update this</td>")
new_content = regex.sub("<td>updated</td>", content)

soupx = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new_content, features="html.parser")
soup=str(soupx)
payload={"body":{"storage":{"value":soup,"representation":"storage"}}}
sendrequest = requests.put(url=address, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
```

i couldn't find what is the issue.
can someone help on this

Comment: I cannot see where do you define `address` and `headers` ?  Might be worth trying to call `request.get()` (without `.json()` ) to see what is returned - the error looks like it is trying to convert `None` to json

Comment: Hello, everything is looks good until soup variable.
as when I print(soup) i can see the correct response
but when I send the request.put I hit that error

Comment: and what about `requests.put(url=address, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)` without `.json()`